# ReactJS setState with multidimensional object and dynamic key

Tags: reactjs

My State is as follows:

```
this.state = {
  Form: {},
  Result: {
    Duplicate: false,
    ServerError: false
  }
};
```

I want to dynamically add to the `Form` object with field values as they're entered, so I try the standard way to add dynamic keys:

```
handleChange(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  const name = target.name;
  this.setState({
    Form[name]: value
  });
}
```

But this produces this syntax error:

```
  66 |         const name = target.name;
  67 |         this.setState({
> 68 |             Form[name]: value
     |                 ^
  69 |         });
  70 |         console.log(this.state)
  71 |     }
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is the correct way to achieve it

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  Form: {
    ...prevState.Form,
    [name]: value,
  }
}));
```

Comment: I appreciate :)

Answer (score 4):

You've just used invalid syntax to create a dynamic object key. You need do this:

```
this.setState({
    Form: {
       ...this.state.Form,
       [name]: value
    }
});
```

Comment: I get `68:14  error  'Form' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: Ah yes I see. Both your syntax is invalid but your implementation won't work. Separate problems :)

Comment: That just writes key named `undefined` on the state object